# How to program AllJoyn Explorer

Tags: c#, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core, alljoyn

I am trying to develop a UWP application using C# that will discover all AllJoyn producers on the network and create consumer objects for communicating with the devices(producers). It's going to be pretty much **a generic consumer** like the [AllJoyn Explorer](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/AllJoyn/AllJoynExplorer) in the Windows 10 IoT Core Samples on github.

Is the source code for the AllJoyn Explorer available for developers?

If not can I get some insight or guides to writing such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AllJoyn Explorer is based on the DeviceProviders code here: https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/AllJoyn/Platform/DeviceProviders

This is the meat of it all. I packed it all up into an easy to use nuget package here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/dotMorten.AllJoyn.DeviceProviders/

..and I wrote a tutorial on how to use it here: https://www.hackster.io/dotMorten/discovering-and-interacting-with-any-alljoyn-device-0dbd86?ref=user&ref_id=31739&offset=0

Answer (score 1):

the AllJoyn Explorer source code is not provided yet.
https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AllJoyn.htm
You can use the Universal sample available on GitHub as a good starting point. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AllJoyn